# Регулярные выражения. Поиск подстроки.

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Помогите плз. составить регэксп для поиска подстроки (пришедшей от пользовтаеля) которая может содержать метасимволы. Предварительно проходить по подстроке и экранировать все метасимволы не хотелось бы.

Comment: Не указан язык в рамках которого нужно решение.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что без указания ЯП можно только гадать на каком ЯП нужно решение. Плюс в нагрузку вопрос устарел и на него нет качественных ответов.

Answer (score 2):

Сильно зависит от используемого языка программирования, так например в perl/php:

```
/\Q$substing\E/
```

Comment: А для Oracle?

Comment: Тут я пас - нужно читать какую библиотеку использует Oracle, если pcre - то все ОК, если что-то свое - нужно читать

Answer (score 2):

А почему именно регексп? Можно попытаться найти позицию подстроки в тексте. И если оно найдется, то эта подстрока в строке есть.

```
instr(lower(fieldName), lower(userStr))
```

Что-то вроде этого...